# How to use properties in functions

Tags: javascript

Please see the code below
‍‍‍‍‍‍

```
function tehran() {
    // some code
}

tehran.tower = "Milad";
```

how i can print 'tower' properties?
This is possible?

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit on what you mean by "use 'tower' properties"?

Comment: For example, I want to print it

Comment: Does using `console.log` not work?

Comment: @jps functions are also objects and can have properties. So, this is *valid code*. Whether it makes sense is another matter - there is an extremely narrow set of use-cases where you'd really want this.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks - removed my comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

functions are just callable objects, with a special meaning for `this` which is not self-referencing like an object method.

However, you can always refer to the function itself:

```
function tehran() {
  console.log(tehran.tower); // "Miland"
}

tehran.tower = "Milad";

tehran();
```